# What is the meaning of 不同而不同?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is taken from the phrase:

> 口感依成分不同而不同

Sounds like it means "manifold" or something like that?

Comment: The taste `varies` according to `different` ingredients. The first `不同` refers to `different`, and the second refers to `varies`.

Comment: As noted above, the first 不同 is an adjective ("different") while the second one is a verb (differ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, here the real pattern that you should focus on is “依[A]而[B]", which means "according to A, B is/does...",remember 依 means "according to, based on" here. So your example means:

> *The tastes are different, according to differen ingredients.*
>
> Or you would say, *The tastes of different ingredients are different.*

Another example:

> 单价依采购量而定。 *The unit price is determined based on the purchase quantity.*